# roscreate-pkg: command not found

Tags: ros, roscreate-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there
I'm new in working with ROS. I'm trying to create a package by the following command:

> > roscreate-pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp

but I get the following error

> > roscreate-pkg: command not found

I appreciate if you help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98286/roscreate-pkg:-command-not-found/) by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-11-06**:
Do other ROS bash command work? Like roscd/rosmsg/...

**Comment by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on 2013-11-06**:
Yes, but rospack and roscreate-pkg doesn't work. Btw I'm working with fuerte in ubuntu 12.04

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-11-06**:
Did you source the setup.bash?

**Comment by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on 2013-11-06**:
Thanks aloooot, I forgot to do it!

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-11-06**:
Ok great I'll post it as an answer, so you can accept it.

**Comment by [meriemm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22073/meriemm/) on 2015-04-17**:
hi,i have the same problem i have add the      " source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source ~/hydro_workspace/sandbox/setup.bash  " but i still have the same problem,can you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Source your setup.bash

You may want to put this in your .bashrc

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [meriemm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22073/meriemm/) on 2015-04-17**:
hi,i have the same problem i have add the      " source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source ~/hydro_workspace/sandbox/setup.bash  " but i still have the same problem,can you please help me.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-04-20**:
Sourcing two setup.bash makes no sense. The first `source` gets overwritten by the second one. Have you set up your workspace correctly?